# How to change Google Maps bus stops default icon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to change this bus icon with javascript? It's easy to change markers and and route color and so on, but how to change this icon what is shown on a picture below?

[image: How to change this icon?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API-based way to change these icons.

An option would be to use CSS, example using your avatar instead of the icon:

```
  /*this will hide the bus-icon*/
  img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png"]{
    width:0 !important;
  }

  /*use a custom icon as background for the span which follows the icon*/
  img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png"]+span{
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lcVw.png?s=32&g=1) no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    padding-left:18px;
  }
```

But it's only a workaround, it will only work as long as the markup for these tooltips or the src of the icon will not be changed.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution and answer suited for my needs the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Creating your own custom marker in the same place.

Edit: this might work.

```
function changeSourceAll() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].src.indexOf('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png') !== -1) {
            images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png", "NEWICON.png");
        }
    }
}

changeSourceAll();
```

Comment: This isn't the solution because this icon's position is not static.

Comment: No, i meant this bus icon is not staitc. Its position is different when the route is different. Adding marker to static position doesnt resolve the problem. Is there a way to just change this bus icon?

Comment: If the icon is hosted on your server's part and not on google's part of the api, then you could try to find the bus icon in the maps api code.

Comment: This icon is from Google: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png

Comment: It is good solution and nice approach, but for me the css solution is easier to implement. Btw, your answer is correct too ;)