# How to change the icon of transit stations in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a google map with custom styling. I would like change the appearance of the rail and bus stations icons to my own png but they do not seem to function like other markers. Is it possible to change them?

[image]

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071108/how-to-change-google-maps-bus-stops-default-icon

Comment: @user2314737 perhaps I'm missing something there about the implementation but the suggested answer there for me doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps the url of the png has changed?

Comment: Have you tried to modify icon's URL? based on the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons), [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon) objects define an image. They also define the `size` of the icon, the `origin` of the icon and the `anchor` where the icon's hotspot should be located.

Comment: @d.datul1990 I've tried this but perhaps the url of the image has since changed or I'm missing something about the implementation. 


`/*this will hide the bus-icon*/
  img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png"]{
    width:0 !important;
  }

  /*use a custom icon as background for the span which follows the icon*/
  img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus.png"]+span{
    background:url(http://i.stack.imgur.com/8lcVw.png?s=32&g=1) no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    padding-left:18px;
  }`

Comment: I suspect your only option is to hide the icons (using styled maps) and add markers in the same locations

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to hide the transit icons (or just the bus icons), and put markers of your choice in the same locations. You do then need the locations of the stops.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2ha4vmma/5/)

[image: screen shot of result]

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 53.3507456,
      lng: -6.2393441
    },
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    styles: [{
      featureType: 'transit',
      elementType: 'labels.icon',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }]
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < transitStops.length; i++) {
    var tmark = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: transitStops[i],
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: "https://www.geocodezip.net/mapIcons/bus_blue.png",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 5)
      }
    })
  }


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    console.log("{placeId:" + evt.placeId + ", lat: " + evt.latLng.lat() + ", lng: " + evt.latLng.lng() + "}");
  });
}
var transitStops = [{
  placeId: "ChIJP_OC240OZ0gRTwu09OWnk_U",
  lat: 53.347913,
  lng: -6.247165
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJFZJPbY0OZ0gRp8t6ffAVCWE",
  lat: 53.347695,
  lng: -6.243303
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJOd0OQI0OZ0gRUKpFv3o7AEQ",
  lat: 53.347759,
  lng: -6.242445
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJe1pTa40OZ0gR_e129---hi8",
  lat: 53.347746,
  lng: -6.24193
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJKzM8uvIOZ0gRtYKquNyaiYc",
  lat: 53.347528,
  lng: -6.239698
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJywS6evIOZ0gRhNm96pmOHlU",
  lat: 53.347388,
  lng: -6.236351
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJF-4BzfMOZ0gRkEbmpj60Ub0",
  lat: 53.349668,
  lng: -6.235256
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJQ6qDDfMOZ0gRBfF7TUP_Zi8",
  lat: 53.350398,
  lng: -6.238668
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJQ9tx_PMOZ0gRJsmjoHdrYEI",
  lat: 53.351781,
  lng: -6.23502
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJX9g7SvEOZ0gRys5vUWlD7aE",
  lat: 53.352063,
  lng: -6.233089
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJH3fLzfYOZ0gR4UOqoWvdNhw",
  lat: 53.352639,
  lng: -6.232402
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJn_6n1_YOZ0gRtovXaObKKWE",
  lat: 53.352959,
  lng: -6.231608
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJXWdle4wOZ0gRGAyVKltGjlA",
  lat: 53.351128,
  lng: -6.245534
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJ81mp4IsOZ0gROlwgkhh__eA",
  lat: 53.35287,
  lng: -6.248538
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJtanR-PAOZ0gRydiUCW5F6VE",
  lat: 53.349911,
  lng: -6.230235
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJ86GfP_QOZ0gRxuS4lSrV_EU",
  lat: 53.35366366064975,
  lng: -6.236715316772461
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJ2XaPUvQOZ0gRdutDSaj0Ko4",
  lat: 53.354649828682476,
  lng: -6.23798131942749
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJT6lqq_UOZ0gRr00DPcLv8WU",
  lat: 53.35484193668282,
  lng: -6.238517761230469
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJPWurjI8OZ0gRgRn4fsIACMc",
  lat: 53.347169750741884,
  lng: -6.25422477722168
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJpWwGCJEOZ0gRPZ-JB7vXAAU",
  lat: 53.343377977116916,
  lng: -6.248044967651367
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJW6E5POsOZ0gRhU0Mt66cLcg",
  lat: 53.33979085385975,
  lng: -6.2381744384765625
}, {
  placeId: "ChIJG4-0NcIOZ0gRbapaqYSiEm0",
  lat: 53.33384581380873,
  lng: -6.22899055480957
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks. I appreciate the effort, I should've updated this when I solved it. Unfortunately this wasn't an option for me as I needed to retain the ability to click a bus stop and have it show you which buses stopped there. Hopefully it helps someone else though! In the end I ended up making all the icons black by messing with I think the gamma property? And that was ok for me but if I needed other colours I would've had to go your route.