# how to resize stock labels or markers for points of interest on google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering how to resize the labels and components in info windows (like the buttons displayed) that are assigned by google maps on points of interest, namely the bus ones, as they're only visible at a particular zoom level, and even then are super hard to see.  I know how to create ones on top of bus stops but I'd rather just resize the ones that are already provided.  [image]

Comment: Those are built into the map tiles.  Any control over their display would be with a [StyledMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Comment: when I reviewed the docs, and I really focused on the part that you linked to as well as on markers, I couldn't find anything regarding resizing the icons, only making them visible or changing color values with regards to styling.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to change the icon of transit stations in google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249195/how-to-change-the-icon-of-transit-stations-in-google-maps)